# Why logstash concatinates topics?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I have pipeline kafka→logstash→elasticsearch
I created two topics in kafka: test-1 and test-2
Write manually to these topics messages: 67 into test-1 and 67 into test-2.
I wrote two logstash workers

test1.conf

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "172.29.39.115:9093,172.29.39.116:9093"
        topics => "test-1"
        #consumer_threads => 2
        client_id => "logstash-test-1"
        group_id => "logstash-test-1-0"
        security_protocol => "SSL"
        ssl_keystore_location => "/opt/logstash/config/server.keystore.p12"
        ssl_keystore_password => "passwd"
        ssl_truststore_location => "/opt/logstash/config/truststore.jks"
        ssl_truststore_password => "passwd"
        #ssl_endpoint_identification_algorithm => ""
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["172.29.39.141:9200", "172.29.39.142:9200", "172.29.39.143:9200", "172.29.39.144:9200"]
        ssl => true
        cacert => "/etc/certificates/salt-ca.crt"
        user => logstash_internal
        password => "passwd"
        index => "test-1"
    }
}
```

test2.conf

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "172.29.39.115:9093,172.29.39.116:9093"
        topics => "test-2"
        #consumer_threads => 2
        client_id => "logstash-test-2"
        group_id => "logstash-test-2-0"
        security_protocol => "SSL"
        ssl_keystore_location => "/opt/logstash/config/server.keystore.p12"
        ssl_keystore_password => "passwd"
        ssl_truststore_location => "/opt/logstash/config/truststore.jks"
        ssl_truststore_password => "passwd"
        #ssl_endpoint_identification_algorithm => ""
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["172.29.39.141:9200", "172.29.39.142:9200", "172.29.39.143:9200", "172.29.39.144:9200"]
        ssl => true
        cacert => "/etc/certificates/salt-ca.crt"
        user => logstash_internal
        password => "passwd"
        index => "test-2"
    }
}
```

I thought that I will have two indices in Elasticsearch, test-1 with 67 docs and test-2 with 60 docs, but I have test-1 with 127 docs and test-2 with 127 docs.

What I doing wrong?

**Update**.

I am starting logstash as service.

`ExecStart=/opt/logstash/bin/logstash "--path.settings" "/opt/logstash/config" "--path.config" "/opt/logstash/config/conf.d/"`

**Update**
Solution is deleting `"--path.config" "/opt/logstash/config/conf.d/"` from service and configure `pipelines.yml` to each pipeline like this:

```
#- pipeline.id: main
  #  path.config: "/opt/logstash/config/conf.d/*.conf"
- pipeline.id: test-1
  path.config: "/opt/logstash/config/conf.d/test1.conf"
  pipeline.workers: 3
- pipeline.id: test-2
  path.config: "/opt/logstash/config/conf.d/test2.conf"
  pipeline.workers: 3
```

Comment: This is the default behavior if you do not configure the [pipelines.yml](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html) to run multiple pipelines or if you start logstash with the `-f` parameter pointing to a folder with configs. You need to configure the `pipelines.yml`. How are you starting logstash? Via command line? As a service? Update your question with this information.

Comment: FWIW, Kafka Connect would not have done this